# How to convert a dataframe to an RDD in scala, not losing the schema of the dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, rdd

My dataframe is as follows:

```
storeId| dateId|projectId
 9     |2457583|     1047
 9     |2457576|     1048
```

When i do `rd = resultDataframe.rdd` rd only has the data and not the header information. I confirmed this with rd.first where i dont get header info. Also when i try

```
rd.map(f => f._1+"\t"+f._2+"\t"+f._3).saveAsTextFile("s3://pathinS3/testtab4")
```

i only see

```
9     2457583     1047
9     2457576     1048
```

I would like to be able to convert the resultDataframe into a tab separated csv and store it in s3.

Expected csv output in s3:

```
storeId     dateId      projectId
 9          2457583     1047
 9          2457576     1048
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So do you want to put the schema information on all the data partitions ?

Comment: I am already doing repartition(1) so i have just one partition in resultDataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
val rdd = df.rdd
val data = rdd.map(_.mkString("\t"))
val header = sc.parallelize(Seq(df.columns.mkString("\t")))
val rddWitHeader = header.union(data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked.
Just had to add rddWitHeader.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("s3Location")

Answer (score 2):

I have a workaround for this:

```
val columns= resultDataFrame.columns
val rddOfheader=sc.parallelize(columns)
val rddtoBesaved=resultDataFrame.rdd.map(f => (f.getAs[String](0),f.getAs[String](1),f.getAs[String](2))
val unionRDD=rddOfheader.unionAll(rddtoBeSaved)
unionRDD.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("foo.txt")
```

P.S: Code is not tested , but this should work, and would be happy to see a much easy answer but this should work.

Comment: val unionRDD=rddOfheader.union(rddtoBesaved)
<console>:60: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, String)]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
       val unionRDD=rddOfheader.union(rddtoBesaved)

Could you check this please.

Comment: Helped me get the idea to derive columns and use union. Thanks.

Comment: The required:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] error should disappear with import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD